# ElasticSearch geo_bounding_box coordinate format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, tire

I was following the ElasticSearch guide online to represent coordinates as "lat, lng" but it doesnt seem to be working until I flip everything around to "lng, lat". I even have to flip around top_left and bottom_right in order for the query to work.

Is anyone experiencing the same problem? Clearly this is not how the documentation says to use it, but it's only working when I format it this way.

Rails format

```
def self.search(params)
      tire.search( page: params[:page], per_page: 2 ) do
           query { all }
           filter :geo_bounding_box, location: { top_left: " -121.88596979687497, 37.33588487375733", bottom_right: " -122.43528620312497, 37.553946238118264" }
      end
end
```

CURL format

```
curl -X GET "http://localhost:9200/articles/article/_search?page=&per_page=2&size=2&pretty=true" -d '{"query":{"match_all":{}},"facets":{"condition":{"terms":{"field":"condition","size":10,"all_terms":false}}},"filter":{"geo_bounding_box":{"location":{"top_left":" -121.88596979687497, 37.33588487375733","bottom_right":" -122.43528620312497, 37.553946238118264"}}},"size":2}'
```

Console response

```
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 169,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [ {
      "_index" : "articles",
      "_type" : "article",
      "_id" : "4f72bc7d0bdb820f02000002",
      "_score" : 1.0, "_source" : {"content":"words here!","location":[37.444995,-122.160628],"name":"harro"}
    }, {
      "_index" : "articles",
      "_type" : "article",
      "_id" : "4fdf0cf20bdb82336c000002",
      "_score" : 1.0, "_source" : {"content":"Run of the mill","location":[37.33588487375733,-121.88596979687497],"name":"Billy Bob"}
    } ]
  },
  "facets" : {
    "condition" : {
      "_type" : "terms",
      "missing" : 5597,
      "total" : 0,
      "other" : 0,
      "terms" : [ ]
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When geo point is specified as a string, it should be in `"lat,lon"` format. When it is specified as an array, it should be in `[lon, lat]` format.

Comment: any reason for this? It sounds counterintuitive

Comment: The string representation follows standard convention for geographic coordinates, while array representation follows [GeoJSON](http://www.geojson.org/) standard. There is an [interesting discussion on stackexchange](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6037/latlon-or-lonlat-whats-the-right-way-to-display-coordinates-and-inputs) about some historical reasons for these differences.